# Is there any Java Based 2D Cross Platform Mobile Game Engine Out There?

Tags: java, android, ios, game-engine

I have knowledge about JAVA programming and i can built Android Apps.
I have created Simple 2D Android Game the problem is All Game Engines mostly based on C++,JavaScript, HTML5.
 I'm not familiar with these technologies.
I need to deploy my Android Game Project to iOS which uses Objective-C Programming language.
So Is there any platform that i can put my JAVA(+Android) Code and deploy other platforms(iOS , WindowsPhone(is a plus)) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) gaming framework.. Its based on java, and is cross platform